# not able to accees inner properties of event inside directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a directive with on click method

```
  @Directive({
selector: '[clickOutside]'
   })
 export class ClickOutsideDirective {
constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
}

@Output()
public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {

    if (!targetElement) {
        return;
    }

    const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside) {

        console.log(event)
       console.log(event.path) =>gives error,not able to compile

        console.log("targetelement",targetElement)
        console.log("native element",this._elementRef.nativeElement)
        this.clickOutside.emit(event);
    }
}
}
```

I WANT TO ACCESS THE PATH PROPERTY OF event. when i console.log(event) its getting and i can see the path property, but when i tried to access event.path
i am getting compilation error, why it is so? how can i access the current click event and its inner properties inside the onClick method?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `path`property listed in the [documentation for MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), nor in the documentation of its superclasses. And as you discovered, there is no such `path` property in the TypeScript definition of MouseEvent either.

So you want to use a property that exists at runtime, in your browser, but that is not documented, and thus probably not standard, and thus probably non-existent in other browsers. You're free to do so, but you should be aware of the risks. Just use `event['path']` instead of `event.path`.

Comment: is there any alternative solution? i need the best way

Comment: i just want to check whether the parent div of whatever element i clicked has an id "datepicker"... thats what iam trying to do

Comment: Then you should not get the path of the event. You should get the parent element of the target of the event.